# Handling decimal separator changes between simulator and device

Tags: ios, number-formatting

I do some math stuff with doubles in my app. This works great on the simulator, which uses periods to make decimals. When I run it on my iPhone though, I have a comma instead. When I use a comma it does not do anything.

How can I modify so the stuff either thinks of commas as a period or change the keyboards (I am using the decimal pad) so I get period input on all languages?

Comment: I think this works exactly as it should. This is not a bug, just that in some countries (e.g. the Nederlands) commas are used instead of periods (`$ 2,13` instead of `$ 2.13`). It's really frustrating though ...

Comment: Yep, because the math does not work with commas. I know its an intended feature to be correct with the local language, but I need a way to alter it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on language settings sometimes you will see commas sometimes periods.

For your math, take in the user inputs, and just do validation on the values to make sure they use the correct formatting for your equations.  Possibly save the preference of comma or period and then reformat the output so the user will be familiar with the formatting.

```
- (void)validateUserInputs{
    for(UIControl *control in self.view.subviews){
        if([control isMemberOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
            NSString *convertedText = [[(UITextField *)control text] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."];
            [(UITextField *)control setText:convertedText];
        }
    }

    for(UIControl *control in self.view.subviews){
        if([control isMemberOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
            NSLog(@"Converted String Value: %@", [(UITextField *)control text]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: sure, i'm guessing user inputs are coming from something like a textfield?

Comment: Yep! Text fields converted to doubles through `double inputText = [inputTextField.text doubleValue] / 100;` the /100 is because i'm using %. The double is later used in a double array `double array [10]` and stuff, so I need them in a format where I can still use them there!

Comment: For further documentation, [here](http://pastebin.com/gKiwhFr5) is the whole thing thats relevant to the code, and [here](http://i.imgur.com/86b0y.png) is the UI.

Comment: the validation i added to my posts should replace any commas for periods, and you can modify that method slightly to replace periods for commas before you show your output to the screen

Comment: Nice, thanks! If you look at the code i linked in my last comment, would I need one of these for each text field or does it do the work for all of them?

Comment: it iterates through all textfields in your uiand tries to validate them.

Comment: Great! Last noob question, how do i declare this into my project?

Comment: I put it in my VC and just called `[self validateUserInputs];`  in my sample i just made i had a button that before doing any calculations i called validate inputs, then ran calculations then reformatted to orig.  Check out scanners, like mentioned in the other answer.  They are more powerful and may provide a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

As @propstm says, different regions/locales use different number delimiters.  [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the standard framework class for converting text to numeric types, and takes into account all conventions of the user's current locale.  You should use it for your conversions from text input to doubles.

However, simply replacing commas with periods is not adequate because, for instance, in the US Locale $1,234.56 is a valid value for a currency. If you simply replace commas with periods, this becomes invalid.

Use NSScanner. This is what it's specifically designed for.

**EDIT**

You might also consider using an `NSNumberFormatter` with your `UITextField`. It can really help with validating user input before you even scan it with `NSScanner`.  [Check it out](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Example of `NSNumberFormatter` use:

Set your viewController as the delegate of the UITextField, and add this method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *proposedNewValue = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    return (nil != [numberFormatter numberFromString:resultString]);
}
```

This will make it so the field won't accept improperly formatted numbers. You can also use this method to get the `NSNumber` from the text.

To use `NSScanner` you could do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)doStuff:(id)sender
{
    NSString* entry = textField.text;
    double value = 0;

    if ([[NSScanner scannerWithString:entry] scanDouble: &value])
    {
        // If we get here, the scanning was successful
    }
    else
    {
        // Scanning failed -- couldn't parse the number... handle the error
    }
}
```

HTH.

Comment: Yep, looks like a scanner is a beefed up version of string replacement!  Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: This is numbers tho, not currency. Still need to use Scanner?

Comment: Yes. NSScanner is not limited to currency. 1,234,567.89 is also a valid number in the US locale and is not a currency, and would summer a similar fate.

Comment: Great, thanks. This seems like the stuff I want, tho wouldn't this give me an awefull load of code with 11 text fields i need to format? If you look at the links to my project I postet as a comment in the answer  propstm made, is this the best way to do it?

Comment: You can use the one delegate/delegate method for all text fields that have the same formatting requirements. You can even use a single delegate/delegate method for text fields with different formatting requirements, but you'll have to check which field is passed in and have a condition that enforces the right formatting.